# Create cloudfoundry task using private repo docker image

Tags: docker, cloud-foundry

We have a requirement to deploy private repo docker image as cloudfoundry task, then invoke the task from cloudfoundry javabuildpack spring boot application.

I am following this approach, 
    - I tried to create droplet id for docker image 
    - then invoke the droplet using cf v3 task API.

Code Steps:

```
export CF_DOCKER_PASSWORD=<hsdp docker service passwork>
export CF_DOCKER_USERNAME=<hsdp docker service key>

cf v3-create-package myspringboot-app --docker-image <private-repo>/eng-bdp_bdp-dev/etlwithpython:1
cf v3-stage myspringboot-app --package-guid a3bd45cd-eb5f-4072-bee8-af0bd389f13a
```

The v3 stage command is throws below error.

```
"Stager error: Failed to get blobstore download url for package a3bd45cd-eb5f-4072-bee8-af0bd389f13a"
```

Please let me know this approach is correct and how to solve this error.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to do [this](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/using-tasks.html#run-tasks):

1. Push your application.  Even if it won't start successfully because it's just designed as a task, just push it and once staging completes, you can run `cf stop`.
2. Then just `cf run-task APP-NAME "TASK" --name TASK-NAME`.

I think this will be the simplest and most straight forward option.  If that doesn't work for some reason you could try the following.  The v3 api is not stable though, so this could change/break/stop working in the future.

1. Run `cf push` but with the `--no-start` option.  This will upload your package and create an app for you.
2. Run `cf v3-packages <app>` and get the package uuid.
3. Run `cf v3-stage <app> --package-guid <uuid>`.  This will stage the app and create a droplet.
4. Run `cf v3-droplets <app>` and uuid of the droplet you just created.
5. Run `cf v3-set-droplet <app> -d <uuid>`, to associate the app with the droplet you created.
6. Run `cf run-task <app> <cmd>` to execute your task.

Hope that helps!